# How do I put custom colorful image in a UITabBar?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add a custom image to the UITabBar but it loses its color. I guess it's because of the tintColor.

What I get:

[image: What I get]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .menuColor
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .gray
        
        setupVCs()
    }
    
    private func createNavController(for rootViewController: UIViewController,
                                     title: String,
                                     image: UIImage,
                                     imageInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)) -> UIViewController {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        navController.tabBarItem.title = title
        navController.tabBarItem.image = image
        navController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = imageInsets
        navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        rootViewController.navigationItem.title = title
        return navController
    }
    
    private func setupVCs() {
        viewControllers = [
            createNavController(for: ViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("notes", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "notes")!),
            createNavController(for: ViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "rec")!, imageInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)),
            createNavController(for: ViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("settings", comment: ""), image: UIImage(named: "settings")!)
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think from, very bad memory, you need to use something like `UIImage(named: "notes").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tabBarItem.image = tabBarImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Try this solution